# Full image size with Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How can i get the full image size with Fancybox?

It is always resized to viewport. and for one of my project I don't need that.

I tried different options (fitToView, etc.) but i didn't succeed to get the full image size.

It seems that i'm not the only person with this issue: [Using fancybox to view full sized image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919330/using-fancybox-to-view-full-sized-image)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so your question is exact duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using fancybox to view full sized image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919330/using-fancybox-to-view-full-sized-image)

Answer (score 16):

The question might be duplicated but it may have a different answer. Actually [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919330/using-fancybox-to-view-full-sized-image) apart of being very old and it was never answered, is about how to customize a functionality not existing in fancybox v1.3.x (dynamically resize an image to its full size once is already opened in fancybox). Such functionality has been introduced with the "`buttons`" helper in fancybox v2.x

On the other hand, if you just want to display images in their original size (not resized to fit in the view port) then: for fancybox v2.x use the API option `fitToView: false`. For fancybox v1.3.x use `"autoScale": false`

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 // if fancybox 1.3.x
 "autoScale": false
 // if fancybox 2.x
 fitToView: false
 //
 // don't use both
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works great!
I bought the 2.0 version of Fancybox but I was using version 1.3.4 on the website who needed full size. So i was trying to use 2.0 options on a 1.3.4 version... fail...